# Problem to make the drop down menu dynamic

Tags: dynamic, dropdown, angular8

I have been doing a project in which I need to create a dynamic drop down menu. In this project I am been using Angular 8 and bootstrap 4

The piece of code of html

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">

                <li ng-model="getOrders" ng-repeat="order in orders">
                        <a ng-click="getOrders()">{{orders}}</a> 

                    //also tried {{ order.name }} - no result


                      </li>
          <!-- <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> -->
        </div>
      </li>
```

The above code is taken from the bootstrap site with the dropdown code:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

and I have tried to use it with the below which I found in the Internet:

```
<span class="dropdown" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
  <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
    Click me!
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
      <a ng-click="runFn(choice.fn)">{{choice.name}}</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

The code from component.ts from some tutorial:

```
form: FormGroup;
orders = [];

public someinfo:String = "";
public info:String = "";

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  orders: ['']
});

this.orders = this.getOrders();

}

ngOnInit() {
}

getOrders() {
return [
  { id: '1', name: 'order 1' },
  { id: '2', name: 'order 2' },
  { id: '3', name: 'order 3' },
  { id: '4', name: 'order 4' }
];
}


After compiling the project and clicking the Dropdown Menu, the       
result is like below:

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Could you please point me out, how should I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below?

Define how each order is going to look like outside your component class

```
interface OrderEntity
{
    id : string;
    name : string;
}
```

Inside you component class specify that, orders array will have the same structure

```
orders: OrderEntity[] = [];
```

With in getOrders try and push data into orders array

```
getOrders()
{
    this.order.push({id : '1', name : 'order1'});
}
```

On the template you ca access orders as list and access each item by doing `let item of orders;` and obtain its attributes `{{item.id}}` and `{{item.name}}`

Comment: Thanks for replaying RR1112, I tried the above and an error occurred: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'OrderEntity[]'

Comment: @bartosz - At which line is it complaining?  If at order: OrderEntity[]= []; you can also do order: OrderEntity[];

Comment: it complains at line where is the piece - this.orders = this.getOrders(); with 'this.orders' being underlined in red color. I tried to shorten  the form from this form orders:OrderEntity[] = []; to this orders:OrderEntity[]; but it still fails with comment - Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'OrderEntity[]'.

Comment: Right. You don't need to do this.orders= this.getOrders(); as getOrders is not returning anything! It only modifies(i.e pushes items) this.orders and this.orders can be directly used in template. Just invoke this.getOrders(); instead of this.orders = this.getOrders(); Hope this helps.

Comment: stil the same problem

Comment: Actually right now, I am having different problem: it threw an error like:  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at CrudNavComponent.getOrders (crud-nav.component.ts:64) and this is in the line where the piece is: return this.orders.push({id : '1', name : 'order1'});

Comment: Initializing the orders array may help order: OrderEntity[]= []; If not please post your updated code to provide better assistance

Comment: Thanks for help @RR1112, I think I found a little bit different way to do it. If I have some more troubles with this project I will ask you for help, if it's possible of course.